# mysql文の作成についてご質問がございます。

Tags: mysql

下記のテーブル3つから、必要なデータを取得したいです。

```
テーブル名：test1
カラム名
id
p_id  test2.p_id と紐づきます
point (1～3が入ります)

テーブル名：test2
カラム名
id
p_id
s_id  test2.s_id と紐づきます

テーブル名：test3
カラム名
id
s_id
u_id  こちらのカラムがs_idのグループになります。
```

取得したいデータは、u_id,point1(1の件数),point2(2の件数),point3(3の件数) のリストを取得したいです。

```
select u_id,count(point) from test3 
left join test2 on test3.s_id = test2.s_id 
left join test1 on test1.s_id = test3.s_id 
where point = 1 group by u_id
```

上記を実行致しますと、u_id,point1(1の件数) のリストしか取得できません。point2(2の件数),point3(3の件数)を取得したい場合、どのようにSQLを記述すればいいでしょうか。ご教授頂けますと助かります。

Comment: テーブル定義をCreate文でSQLで記述してもらえると、より詳細にテーブルの状態がわかるので回答が得られると思います。あとさしつかえなければtest1~3といった抽象的なものだとイメージがつきづらいので、現実世界のものに置き換えてもらえるとよりわかりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[条件付COUNT](https://accelboon.com/tn/mysql-%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7count%E3%80%81sum%E3%80%81avg%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)で対応可能です。

COUNTは[nullを計上しない](https://www.softel.co.jp/blogs/tech/archives/3267)特性を活かすために`{条件式} or null`を記述することがポイントです。

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c133e3/3)

```
select u_id,
       count(point=1 or null) point1,
       count(point=2 or null) point2,
       count(point=3 or null) point3
from test3 
left join test2 on test3.s_id = test2.s_id 
left join test1 on test1.p_id = test3.p_id -- 質問文のs_idをp_idに書き換え
group by u_id
```